# Manifest merger failed android:exported

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, intellij-idea

https://i.stack.imgur.com/OHfBH.png
https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ma6Rc.png

hi there I am new for IntelliJ-idea and android and i have got this error and by looking through the internet the solution was adding   **android: exported="true"**  but I still get the same error help please !

Comment: show error logs or stack trace

Answer (score 0):

You need to set `android:exported="true"` in your launcher activity, like this if your app is targeting `Android 12`:

```
 <activity
        android:name=".YourLauncherActivity"
        android:exported="true"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```